# How do I slow down a flash game?

Tags: flash, adobe, slowdown

Basically the objective is to click on certain targets, which upon doing so would destroy the target and garner you points. I've written a macro to help me until the point where its impossible to even see the target more than a mere flicker, (maybe even less than that, i cant see it with my eyes). But its possible because i believe others have done so. (Maybe on slower comps?)

Anyway the question is, how would it be possible to **slow down the flash game?** 
I've thought of a couple of ways that could work but i'm not sure how to implement them.

  1. Slow down the cpu speed? (smth like that? how?)

  2. As the game progress the time the targets appear and stay up is reduced. Maybe theres a variable controlling all of this, isit possible to modify the address of this variable? freeze it or smth?

Any ideas, suggestions and especially advice would really be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You want help cheating in a Flash game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

proper flash games are written in a frame rate independant manner. is such cases, you may be able to reduce player performance, the game won't be running slower, but rather more choppy, because all time related events occur based on system time.

if however the game is actually frame based, the easiest is to grab the swf and change the framerate in its [header](http://www.the-labs.com/MacromediaFlash/SWF-Spec/SWFfileformat.html). or create an swf that runs at the desired framerate and load the game into it, forcing the game to run at the containers frame rate.

anyway. if you wanna get a better highscore, than this is probably not the way to go.

greetz
back2dos

Answer (score 2):

**If you are asking how to cheat** on a flash game then download Cheat Engine.

Comment: yeah i've definitely heard about that, it modifies the memory am i right?

Comment: Well i'm not really asking how to cheat, i recall way back in the 199*s my cpu was really slow and an exact copy of a flash game ran very slow on my first cpu and very fast on my second cpu. Is it possible for my second cpu to emulate the speed which the flash game ran on my first cpu? If i'm remember correctly dosbox does this? 
Edit: but for dos games.

Comment: Yes DosBOX does this, although it is an emulator.

Comment: You can also "slow down" (and speed them up) flash games.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution 8 years in the future, I wanted to slow down 3d pong because it gets quite hard, I came across a good way to fix it, but it requires you to have something that opens .swf files. Basically, download the .swf file of your game, open it and use cheat engine on the file, works like a charm. To download the .swf just use the inspect menu, find a link that ends in .swf-probably will be named the game's name as well-and click the link, it should auto download. Also note that I use adobe animate to open it, I don't know anything else to open it with but its a start.